# How to subscribe string array so that proper validation errors are displayed

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, file-upload, subscription

I have a parent form where I have drag and drop component and attach list component. Either way, chosen files will be displayed in a list component that will display files in a list format.

However, before uploading I need to validate files for its size and type. My current code is a bit buggy because my validationErrors aren't being reset as the arrayList changes. I think I will need to 'subscribe' to arrayList to do that. My current code doesn't do that though.

This is my parent component HTML:

```
<myform class="o-modal"
  [formGroup]="form"
  [data]="this"
  [startInEditMode]="true"
  #formRef="myForm"
  (lockFailed)="onCancel()"
  (cancelEvent)="onCancel()"
>

  <my-file-drag-drop class="c-documents__drag-drop"
                        [accept]="acceptedFiles"
                        (filesChanged)="addDocument($event)"
                        [showPermissableFiles]="true"
                        [multiple]="true"
                        [showMaximumFileSize]="true"
                        [maxFileSizeMB]="1">
  </my-file-drag-drop>

  <my-attached-file-list [readonly]="false"
                            (toRemove)="removeSelectedDocument($event)"
                            [attachedFiles]="attachedFiles"
                            [accept]="acceptedFiles"
                            [showMaximumFileSize]="true"
                            [maxFileSizeMB]="1"
                            [showPermissableFiles]="true"
                            >
  </my-attached-file-list>
</my-form>
```

This is my parent component ts file:

```
import { AttachedFile } from '../my-attached-file-list/my-attached-file-list.component';

export class MyFileUploadFormComponent implements IFormData, OnInit  {
  @Input() accept: string;
  @Input() maxFileSizeMB = 80;
  @Input() invalid: boolean;
  @Input() showMaximumFileSize = true;
  @Input() showPermissableFiles = true;
  @Input() multiple = true;

  public attachedFiles: Array<AttachedFile> = [];
  public form: UntypedFormGroup;
  public acceptedFiles = getAcceptedFileExtensions();

  constructor(
    public data: File[]
  )
  {
        this.form = formBuilder.group({
        uploadFile: [null],
        description: ['']
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.resetForm();
    this.attachedFiles = this.data;
  }

  async addDocument(files: File[] = null) {
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      this.attachedFiles.push(files[i]);
    }
  }

  async removeSelectedDocument(index: number){
      const documentName = this.attachedFiles.map(item => {return item.name;})
      const response = await this._dialogService
      .openConfirmation(
        'Confirm Delete',
        `Are you sure you want to remove?`,
        'Yes, delete', 'No, cancel', 375
      ).toPromise();

      if (!response){
        return;
      }
      else {
         this.attachedFiles.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
}
```

This is my child component HTML: (this is where I'd like to display all my validation messages. Messages should be on the same line as pdf name)

```
<ul *ngIf="attachedFiles" class="c-my-attached-files__list">
    <li *ngFor="let file of attachedFiles; let i = index" class="c-file" >
        <mat-icon class="c-file__icon" color="primary">upload_file</mat-icon>
        <span class="c-file__name">{{file.name}}</span>
        <ng-container *ngIf="validationErrors">
            <mat-icon [color]='"warn"'>error_outline</mat-icon>
            <span
              *ngFor="let message of validationErrors[i]?.messages" >
              {{ message }}
            </span>
          </ng-container>
        <span class="c-file__size">{{file.size | fileSize }}</span>
        <button *ngIf='!readonly' class="c-file__delete" type="button"
            (click)="removeFile(i)"
            mat-icon-button color="primary"
            aria-label="Delete Added File">
                <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is my child component ts file:

```
export class AttachedFileListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() accept: string;
  @Input() maxFileSizeMB = 80;
  @Input() invalid: boolean;
  @Input() showMaximumFileSize = true;
  @Input() showPermissableFiles = true;
  @Input() multiple = true;
  @Input() readonly = true;
  @Input() attachedFiles: AttachedFile[];

  //not sure what to do here
  testingAttachedFiles: Subject<AttachedFile> = new Subject();

  public validationErrors: { messages: string[] }[] = null;
  private readonly _subscriptions: Subscription = new Subscription();

  @Output() toRemove:EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.validationErrors = this.validateFiles(this.attachedFiles);
  }
  public removeFile(index:number) {
    this.toRemove.emit(index);
  }

 public validateFiles(attachedFiles: AttachedFile[]) {
  const extensions =
    this.accept &&
    this.accept
      .split(',')
      .map((x) => x.toLowerCase().trim())
      .filter((x) => !!x);

  const maxSize = this.maxFileSizeMB * 1024 * 1024;

  return attachedFiles.map((file) => {
    const errors: string[] = [];
    if (
      extensions &&
      !extensions.some((x) => file.name.toLowerCase().endsWith(x))
    ) {
      errors.push(`File Type is not accepted`);
    }

    if (file.size > maxSize) {
      errors.push(`Exceeds maximum file size`);
    }

    if (errors.length > 0) {

      return {
        messages: errors,
      };
    }
    return null;
  });
}
```